# Percentile BarChart with different EdgeForms

Tags: plotting, charts

Is it possible to define different `Edgeform`'s in a in a `BarChart` with `ChartLayout -> "Percentile"`??

E.g. 40 with `Edgeform[Dotted]` and 60 with `Edgeform[Dashed]` (40+60=100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}];
BarChart[{Style[#, EdgeForm[Dashed]], Style[#2, EdgeForm[Dotted]]} & @@@ data, 
 ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

[image]